# TCP/IP connection to the port is failed. sqoop jdbc connection error

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sqoop

When i try to run the sqoop command to import

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/db_name--username 
user--password user--table table_name.
```

I get the following error.

```
ERROR: The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Both my named pipes and TCP/IP are enabled and have port 1433. SQL server TCP/IP protocol also has port 1433. I have created firewall inbound and outbound rules to allow connection.Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add **sqljdbc42.jar** to sqoop lib path and add

> --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

to your sqoop import command.

Also make sure that there should be a space between db_name and --username and space between username and --password and no dot at the end of the command.

Comment: Tried with proper syntax,but still it's the same.it connects to server but not to the database. sqoop list-tables  --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/hadoop_source  --username  hadoop_user --password hadoop_user